# Use postgres sequence in hibernate to increment column value which is not id

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, sequence

I have a increment sequence to column x in table XTable, and i want to tell hibernate to increment value of column by using this sequence. How I can make it. Additional column x is not id and connot be id. Anyone know the way to solve it ?

Liquibase table config

```
<changeSet author="xauthor" id="addXTable">
        <createTable tableName="Xtable">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="x" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="id" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="id_pkey"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Comment: Can somebody help me with that issue ?